# How to create a separate logger for all the imported modules only

Tags: python, logging

I have a python script and it has a logger `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

I have imported many modules in the script (for example: kiteconnect). I wish to have a separate logger for all the imported modules. something like `import_logger = logging.getLogger(**all_modules_excluding__name__**)`

I wish to have separate loggers for the module ( that i am inside) and for the modules ( which I have imported)

How can I do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: The logger created for that module should be left in place and ideally not be reused outside of that module.  So what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The imported modules instantiate a logger and are logging messages and you wish to override those loggers?

Comment: I wish to have separate loggers for the module ( that i am inside) and for the modules ( which I have imported)

Comment: However you declared the logger for the module you are in, why not do the same for the modules you imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not control the source code of the modules you can't stop them from creating their own loggers that all have different names. There is however one feature that helps you: loggers are hierarchical, and unless propagation hasn't been explicitly turned off on them they all will send their logs up to the root logger. So in effect the root logger will have all the logs from all modules. If you turn of propagation on your app logger you effectively have your app logs on that logger, and all module logs in the root logger. You may still have to get the individual modules loggers to set their level. In code it would look something like this:

```
import logging
#import modules here

import_logger = logging.getLogger()
import_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler()) # use any handler you want

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.propagate = False
```